# How do you plot two different y-axes using a loop with twinx?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, twinx

I have a pandas data frame, `region`, containing the prices of flats (`Flat`) and detached properties (`Detached`) in areas of the UK over time (the column `Month`). I'm trying to obtain plots of the change in price over time of both flats and detached properties, so that the plots have two different y axes - both of the average price but in different scales.

I've achieved this by using `twinx()`, however using the code below I get obviously get two figures. The first of these figures is exactly what I want, but I then get a second figure of blank plots. I have attached a screenshot of the kind of plot I want below.

When removing the second fig line `fig, ax2 = ...`, I get the error `NameError: name 'ax2' is not defined`. Also bringing the line `ax2 = ax.twinx()` outside of the loop gives the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'twinx'`. I can't seem to figure out how to get this plot to work without having the duplicate blank figure, any help is much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

region_list = sorted(region['Area'].unique().tolist())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(region_list), figsize=(13.8,len(region_list)*7))
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(nrows=len(region_list), figsize=(13.8,len(region_list)*7))

for i in region_list:
    ind = region_list.index(i)
    filt = region['Area'] == i
    ax2[ind] = ax[ind].twinx()
    ax[ind].plot(region.loc[filt]['Month'],region.loc[filt]['Flat'], color='red', marker='o')
    ax[ind].set_ylabel('Average price of flats', color='red', fontsize=14)
    ax2[ind].plot(region.loc[filt]['Month'],region.loc[filt]['Detached'],color='blue',marker='o')
    ax2[ind].set_ylabel('Average price of detached properties',color='blue',fontsize=14)
    ax[ind].set_title(i, size=14)
    ax[ind].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=10)
    ax[ind].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a secondary axis for a subplot, the result is a new object, and can't be referenced using array indices like the subplot axes (unless you specifically add the new twin axes to an array).

You've probably seen the following:

```py
# with one axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(...)
```

But with multiple subplots, the same logic applies:

```py
# with one axis
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax2 = axes[0].twinx()
ax2.plot(...) # secondary axis on subplot 0

ax2 = axes[1].twinx()
ax2.plot(...) # secondary axis on subplot 1
```

In your case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

region_list = sorted(region['Area'].unique().tolist())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(region_list), figsize=(13.8,len(region_list)*7))

# don't add a second plot - this would be blank
# fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(nrows=len(region_list), figsize=(13.8,len(region_list)*7))

for i in region_list:
    ind = region_list.index(i)
    filt = region['Area'] == i

    # don't index into ax2
    # ax2[ind] = ax[ind].twinx()

    # instead, create a local variable ax2 which is the secondary axis
    # on the subplot ax[ind]
    ax2 = ax[ind].twinx()

    ax[ind].plot(region.loc[filt]['Month'],region.loc[filt]['Flat'], color='red', marker='o')
    ax[ind].set_ylabel('Average price of flats', color='red', fontsize=14)
    ax2.plot(region.loc[filt]['Month'],region.loc[filt]['Detached'],color='blue',marker='o')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Average price of detached properties',color='blue',fontsize=14)
    ax[ind].set_title(i, size=14)
    ax[ind].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=10)
    ax[ind].yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
```